# How to install smart-mode-line powerline theme with use-package

Tags: use-package, powerline, smart-mode-line

I'm trying to move from `el-get` to `use-package`. I am having trouble with `smart-mode-line-powerline-theme`. Emacs complains at startup time with

```
(error "Unable to find theme file for ‘smart-mode-line-powerline’")
```

Here is a minimialized version of a startup file that tries to get the relevant bits to work:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa"     . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"       . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(require 'diminish)
(require 'bind-key)

(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
(put 'use-package 'lisp-indent-function 1)

(use-package powerline) ; seems to be required for smart-mode-line powerline theme

(use-package smart-mode-line
  :config (progn
            (require 'smart-mode-line)
            (setq sml/theme 'respectful)
            (sml/setup)
            (sml/apply-theme 'powerline)))
```

`el-get` creates a directory `emacs.d/el-get/smart-mode-line` containing a git clone of the `smart-mode-line` repository, including a `themes` directory which contains `smart-mode-line-powerline-theme.el` (and a light variant).

`use-package` creates a directory `emacs.d/elpa/smart-mode-line-20170708.1317` which contains the standard sml themes, but **without** the `themes` subdirectory in which the powerline themes live.

How can I get around this glitch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you tried that for example:

```
(use-package smart-mode-line-powerline-theme
   :ensure t
   :after powerline
   :after smart-mode-line
   :config
    (sml/setup)
    (sml/apply-theme 'powerline)
)
```